# How to add space to spinner?

Tags: android

I use an adapter with a custom TextView to make spinner but the space in spinner is very small how can I add space between each item. I try to add padding in a custom TextView nothing happends.

[image]

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting `ClipToPadding`  property of ViewGroup to `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

try setting `ClipToPadding` property of ViewGroup to `FALSE`. This will most probably solve your purpose.!